# Formatting Character strings (First and Last Names) in a long character vector in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, names

I have many names of people in my character vector:

`MLB$Names[1:4]
 [1] "Derek Jeter"   "Robinson Cano"     "Nick Markakis"     "David Ortiz"`

I would like to format them to contain the first inital, with a period, then followed by a space and their last name.  I want it to look like the following

`MLB$NamesFormatted[1:4]
 [1] "D. Jeter"   "R. Cano"     "N. Markakis"     "D. Ortiz"`

I'm assuming the best way to attack this would be by using `grep` or `sub`, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I'm still a rookie at using R, but I'm loving all of its capabilities!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` by capturing the first character as a group (`^(.)`) followed by one or more non-white spaces (`\\S+`) followed by another capture group of one or more white space succeeded by one or more characters (`(\\s+.*)`) to the end (`$`) of the string and replace by the first backreference (`\\1`) followed by a `.` followed by second backreference (`\\2`).

```
sub("^(.)\\S+(\\s+.*)$", "\\1.\\2", MLB$Names)
#[1] "D. Jeter"    "R. Cano"     "N. Markakis" "D. Ortiz"
```

Or it can be done with a compact code of matching one or more lower case letters (`[a-z]+`) and replace it with `.`.

```
sub("[a-z]+", ".", MLB$Names)
#[1] "D. Jeter"    "R. Cano"     "N. Markakis" "D. Ortiz"
```

---

Here is another option with `strsplit` where we split by one or more lower case letters followed by one or more spaces (`[a-z]+\\s+`), loop over the `list` with `vapply` and `paste` the strings together.

```
vapply(strsplit(MLB$Names, "[a-z]+\\s+"), paste, collapse=". ", character(1))
#[1] "D. Jeter"    "R. Cano"     "N. Markakis" "D. Ortiz"
```

#### Data

```
MLB <- data.frame(Names = c("Derek Jeter", "Robinson Cano", 
              "Nick Markakis", "David Ortiz"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strsplit` and `paste`:

```
x <- c("Derek Jeter",   "Robinson Cano",     "Nick Markakis",     "David Ortiz")

sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) paste0(substr(x[1], 1, 1), ". ", x[2]))

[1] "D. Jeter"    "R. Cano"     "N. Markakis" "D. Ortiz"
```

We first split name and surname and we obtain a list; we `sapply` it with an anonymous function that: i) takes the initial of the surname, ii) adds a dot and a space, iii) adds the family name.